# Derived Class Method of Generic Class Template not being called

Tags: templates, generics, swift, ios8, swift-playground

I have a generic class for making and processing JSON API requests.  I pass in the `TParam` and `TResult` template parameters but when I use a derived type it's implementation is not being called.

Here is some code you can throw in a playground to illustrate:

```
import Cocoa

// Base class for parameters to POST to service
class APIParams {
    func getData() -> Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
        return Dictionary<String, AnyObject>()
    }
}

// Base class for parsing a JSON Response
class APIResult {
    func parseData(data: AnyObject?) {

    }
}

// Derived example for a login service
class DerivedAPIParams: APIParams {
    var user = "some@one.com"
    var pass = "secret"

    // THIS METHOD IS CALLED CORRECTLY
    override func getData() -> Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
        return [ "user": user, "pass": pass ]
    }
}

// Derived example for parsing a login response
class DerivedAPIResult: APIResult {
    var success = false
    var token:String? = ""

    // THIS METHOD IS NEVER CALLED
    override func parseData(data: AnyObject?) {
        /*
        self.success = data!.valueForKey("success") as Bool
        self.token = data!.valueForKey("token") as? String
        */

        self.success = true
        self.token = "1234"
    }
}

class APIOperation<TParams: APIParams, TResult: APIResult> {
    var url = "http://localhost:3000"

    func request(params: TParams, done: (NSError?, TResult?) -> ()) {            
        let paramData = params.getData()

        // ... snip making a request to website ...

        let result = self.parseResult(nil)

        done(nil, result)
    }

    func parseResult(data: AnyObject?) -> TResult {
        var result = TResult.self()

        // This should call the derived implementation if passed, right?
        result.parseData(data)

        return result
    }
}

let derivedOp = APIOperation<DerivedAPIParams, DerivedAPIResult>()
let params = DerivedAPIParams()

derivedOp.request(params) {(error, result) in
    if result? {
        result!.success
    }
}
```

The really weird thing is that only the `DerivedAPIResult.parseData()` is not called, whereas the `DerivedAPIParams.getData()` method is called.  Any ideas why?

Comment: Shouldn't you use `protocol` for your base class?
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/Protocols.html

Comment: @Mohsen You can use either. If you use a type, it constrains the class to that type or derived types. If you use a protocol, it constrains to types that implement that protocol. "[Type constraints specify that a type parameter must inherit from a specific class, or conform to a particular protocol or protocol composition.](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/Generics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH26-XID_244)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE: This defect is fixed with XCode 6.3 beta1 (Apple Swift version 1.2 (swiftlang-602.0.37.3 clang-602.0.37))

Added info for a workaround when using XCode 6.1 (Swift 1.1)
See these dev forum threads for details:
https://devforums.apple.com/thread/251920?tstart=30
https://devforums.apple.com/message/1058033#1058033

In a very similar code sample I was having the exact same issue.  After waiting through beta after beta for a "fix", I did more digging and discovered that I can get the expect results by making the base class init() required.

By way of example, here is Matt Gibson's reduced example "fixed" by adding the proper init() to ApiResult

```
// Base class for parsing a JSON Response
class APIResult {
    // adding required init() to base class yields the expected behavior
    required init() {}
}

// Derived example for parsing a login response
class DerivedAPIResult: APIResult {

}

class APIOperation<TResult: APIResult> {
    init() {            
        // EDIT: workaround for xcode 6.1, tricking the compiler to do what we want here
        let tResultClass : TResult.Type = TResult.self
        var test = tResultClass()
        // should be able to just do, but it is broken and acknowledged as such by Apple
        // var test = TResult() 

        println(test.self) // now shows that we get DerivedAPIResult
    }
}

// Templated creation creates APIResult
let derivedOp = APIOperation<DerivedAPIResult>()
```

I do not know why this works.  If I get time I will dig deeper, but my best guess is that for some reason having required init is causing different object allocation/construction code to be generated that forces proper set up of the vtable we are hoping for.

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks for taking the time to put this answer together after  finding a solution.

Comment: Unfortunately this workaround no longer works in Swift 1.1 (XCode 6.1 GM seed).  I will post more info if I get any.

Comment: Edited the answer to show workaround for XCode 6.1 (Swift 1.1)

Comment: This is now actually fixed in XCode 6.3 beta Apple Swift version 1.2 (swiftlang-602.0.37.3 clang-602.0.37)

Answer (score 1):

Looks possibly surprising, certainly. I've reduced your case to something rather simpler, which might help to figure out what's going on:

```
// Base class for parsing a JSON Response
class APIResult {
}

// Derived example for parsing a login response
class DerivedAPIResult: APIResult {
}

class APIOperation<TResult: APIResult> {
    init() {
        var test = TResult()
        println(test.self) // Shows that we get APIResult, not DerivedAPIResult
    }
}

// Templated creation creates APIResult
let derivedOp = APIOperation<DerivedAPIResult>()
```

...so it seems that creating a new instance of a templated class with a type constraint gives you an instance of the constraint class, rather than the derived class you use to instantiate the specific template instance.

Now, I'd say that the generics in Swift, looking through the Swift book, would probably prefer you not to create your own instances of derived template constraint classes within the template code, but instead just define places to hold instances that are then passed in. By which I mean that this works:

```
// Base class for parsing a JSON Response
class APIResult {
}

// Derived example for parsing a login response
class DerivedAPIResult: APIResult {
}

class APIOperation<T: APIResult> {
    var instance: T
    init(instance: T) {
        self.instance = instance
        println(instance.self) // As you'd expect, this is a DerivedAPIResult
    }
}

let derivedOpWithPassedInstance = APIOperation<DerivedAPIResult>(instance: DerivedAPIResult())
```

...but I'm not clear whether what you're trying should technically be allowed or not.

My guess is that the way generics are implemented means that there's not enough type information when creating the template to create objects of the derived type from "nothing" within the template—so you'd have to create them in your code, which knows about the derived type it wants to use, and pass them in, to be held by templated constrained types.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look.  I've filed a bug report for the time being and will try to leave an update when I see a result.

Answer (score -1):

`parseData` needs to be defined as a `class func` which creates an instance of itself, assigns whatever instance properties, and then returns that instance. Basically, it needs to be a factory method. Calling `.self()` on the type is just accessing the type as a value, not an instance. I'm surprised you don't get some kind of error calling an instance method on a type.

Comment: No, a class method wouldn't be able to set the instance values on the derived instance and would essentially be useless for this example.